# Raspberry Ubuntu ARM desktop partitioning

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, raspberrypi, arm, micro-sd

I want to separate and manually set /, /system-boot and /home partitions on my 16GB microSD
There are not options like that in ubuntu installer.
What I should do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a partition tool called 'parted' which is available for Ubuntu.
however its entirely likely that your ubuntu 'writable' (root) partition has been grown to the full size of the SD card.

It will allow you to set limits on the partitions on your SD card.

However its not safe or advisable todo think the root file system whilst your using it.  So you'll need to connect your SD card to another Linux computer to do it.

I suggest you either backup your current SD card or start with a fresh one.
Copy the Ubuntu image to the SD card then via already mounted Linux box (Another Pi will do) parted to create a third partition on the SD stick at the end of the SD card.

Then when you first boot ubuntu it will grow the filesystem to size of the partition you've assigned it and not the entire disk.

```
# parted
GNU Parted 3.3
Using /dev/nvme0n1
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p
Model: TS128GMTE110S (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  269MB  268MB  primary  ext4         boot, lba
 2      269MB   128GB  128GB  primary  ext4
```

There is also a GUI version of parted if your not a CLI user called parted this link here will tell you how to resize your main partition.
https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/software_utilities/disk-tools/gparted
https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/resizing-partitions-disks